# pointing the js file in index file in angular2

Tags: angular

Normally in angular2,in index.html we point the js file which is inside of node_modules folder.can we point only js file seperately in index file  ? . if so,can anyone say how we can achieve that ?

Comment: What do you mean by "can we point only js file seperately"? Maybe you can add some code/examples?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the module loading system you use. For example, if you use Angular CLI, the files you put inside the assets folder can also be referred in index.html.

Comment: angular website are using node_modules to pointing the js file .is there is any other way to point js file ?